# How to return a data from while c# using oracle 11g

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to return all values from my table. How to write a code inside while?

```
var stringConnection = "Data Source = X; User Id = X; Password = X";

var sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";

OracleConnection _oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(stringConnection);

_oracleConnection.Open();

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, _oracleConnection);

var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

var list = new List<dynamic>();

while(dr.Read())
{
    // my doubt is here           
}
return list;
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at Dapper https://riptutorial.com/dapper/learn/100012/dynamic-objects

Comment: Do you wanto to recover all data as a single object or the values can be retrieved one by one?

Comment: Inside while loop create a new object from the reader data and add it to the list. That's what you need to do..

Comment: See my comment in the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var stringConnection = "Data Source = X; User Id = X; Password = X";

var sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";

OracleConnection _oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(stringConnection);

_oracleConnection.Open();

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, _oracleConnection);

var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

var list = new List<dynamic>();

while(dr.Read())
{
    // **** read column name data from table ****
    string Id = (string)dr["Id"];
    string company = (string)dr["company"];
    string city    = (string)dr["City"];
    
    var objItem = new { Id = Id, company = company, city = "city" };
    list.Add(objItem);
    
}
return list;
```

Comment: I am just thinking - if you add string `Id = (string)dr["Id"];`, i.e. you do use named fields, then why use `dynamic`, which is bad for performance. You could do named tuple `List<(string Id, string Company, string City)> list = new List<(string, string, string)>();` I was thinking "full dynamic", i.e. `select *` - you don't know field name. Access only via index

Answer (score 1):

You have several options. 1 - load `DataSet` from `OracleDataReader`. There you will have all your data.

2 - you can still use `select *...` but you need a model. Then create `List<SomeModel>` instead of `List<dynamic>` with

```
while (reader.Read())
{
     model.Property = reader["columnName"]; // will need convert type and take care of DB null. Can use existing extnsions
     . . . . 
}
```

3 - For arbitrary number of columns use `OracleDataReader.FieldCount` and some storage like `List<object[]>`

```
var data = new List<object[]>();
var fCnt = reader.FieldCount;
while (reader.Read())
{
    var arr = new Object[fCnt];
    for(int i = 0; i < fCnt; i++)
        arr[i] = reader[i];
    data.Add(arr);
}
```

The unfortunate part with #3 is that in the end you can get jagged array and not 2-dimentional one but you now have enough info to convert it. But I don't remember when I needed to do #3. So think about #1 and #2

And one more thing - absolutely no need for `dynamic` here. Stay away.